# Proving surjectivity of a linear map, knowing its kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have encountered also this problem.

> Let $T:K^n \rightarrow K^{n-1}$ be a linear map, which has a kernel $ker(T)=\{(\alpha,0,0)\ |\ \alpha \in K\}$. Prove that $T$ is surjective and state any results you use.

I think that I have managed to show that $K^n=K^3$, because $(\alpha,0,0)\in K^n$. So that $T:K^3 \rightarrow K^2$. Can I conclude that $(0,\alpha,0)$ and $(0,0,\alpha)$ do not belong to kernel and hence show that the map is surjective? Thank you very much for your help, friends.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't $(\alpha,0,0,...)$ or $(\alpha,0,...,0)$ or somehting like that?

Comment: I think the kernel it gave you was just for $n=3$ it means $\text{Ker}(T)=\{(\alpha,0,\cdots,0)\in K^n|\alpha\in K\}$ I'm sure

Comment: It would mean that the rank is just $dim(K^n)-1$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the *rank-nullity*  theorem.

Comment: Would love a different way. I must confess, I don't see the link between that and surjectivity. (NOT op BTW)

Comment: $\ker T$ has dimension $1$ by hypothesis, hence you can compute $\dim\operatorname{Im} T$.

Comment: $dim(Im(T))=rank(T)=n-1$ by rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say "I see logically how that works" but couldn't complete the proof. (BTW I really do see that it is surjective! Just not the proof). I'm going to go and do this now.

Comment: @marco11: Exactly.

Comment: @Alec Teal: A linear map $u\colon E\to F$ is surjective if and only if $\operatorname{rank}u=\dim F$.

Comment: $rank(T)=dim(K^{n-1})$, i.e. image and "codomain" have the same dimension. Is this enough to conclude the surjectivity?

Comment: That just shows there's an isomorphism between the image and an $n-1$-dimensional space (over the same field) - oh of course, $T:V\rightarrow\text{Im}(T)$ is surjective.

Comment: @marco11 yeah it is. Composition of surjective functions is surjective

Comment: Absolutely: if $F$ is a subspace of $E$, $E=F\iff\dim F=\dim E$ (all this is true for finite dimensional spaces, of course).

Comment: How do we prove the proposition that a linear map $u:E\rightarrow F$ is surjective if and only if $rank(u)=dim(F)$?

Comment: That is because $\operatorname{rank}u=\dim \operatorname{Im}u=\dim F$, hence $ \operatorname{Im}u=F$.

Comment: ahh, because $Im(u) \subseteq F$. If we know that $Im(u)=F$, then we can conclude that there is one-to-one correspondence, hence $u$ is bijective and then clearly sujective, right?

Comment: @marco11 showing $T:V\rightarrow\text{Im}(T)$ is surjective is easy. If two spaces have the same dimension (over the same field) they are isomorphic (call this map $f:\text{Im}(T)\rightarrow W$) - isomorphisms are injective and surjective. So both $f$ and $T$ are surjective, thus $f\circ T:V\rightarrow W$ is surjective (composition of surjective functions is surjective is EASY to show)

Comment: Thank you guys, linear algebra becomes easy with you.

Comment: @marco11 confirm this theorem (click expand) http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Surjection#The_composition_of_surjective_functions_is_surjective